# How to cluster continuous peak widths

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have a sample data on different prices of a single product and how many times they have been entered in the database. My objective is to determine the optimal price range/(s) for the product based on its frequency in the data set.

This is the price-frequency plot:

[image: Frequency Plot]

I am using Python 3.7.1 on Jupyter. I tried using peak_widths function from the signal library. I got the peak widths, their start points and end points. I made an if-else loop logic but I think I'm going wrong somewhere, I'm getting only a single cluster.

I used this to get peak widths

```
from scipy.signal import peak_widths
pkwdh_106 = signal.peak_widths(count_106, index_106, rel_height=1)
plt.plot(index_106, count_106[index_106], "o"); plt.plot(count_106)
plt.hlines(*pkwdh_106[1:])
plt.xlabel('Price')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
```

This is the peaks' information

```
Width of each peak / maxima :  [7. 5. 4. 7. 2.88888889]
Y level of each width :  [1. 1. 1. 1. 2.]
Starting point of each width :  [ 8. 15. 20. 36. 40.]
Ending point of each width :  [15. 20. 24. 43. 42.88888889]
```

This is the loop that I tried but something is missing here.

```
sum_width = 0
name='cluster('+str(i)+')'
name=[]

start = len(start_x) # Length of starting array is 5
end = len(end_x) # Length of ending array is 5

for i in range(end-1):
    # Iterating till 4 END elements
    for j in range(start-1):
        # Iterating till 4 START elements
        if end_x[i]>=start_x[j+1]:
            # If ending of 1st width is greater than or equal to starting of 2nd width
            sum_width = sum_width + width[i]
            # Add starting of 1st width length to the total sum variable
            name.append(width[i])
            # Adding the width lengths to an array
            print('If loop total width - ', sum_width)
            print('If loop ', name)
        else:
            sum_width = sum_width + width[i]
            # If ending of 1st width is lesser than the starting of 2nd width
            name.append(width[i])
            # Add starting of 1st width length to the total sum variable
            print('Else loop total width - ', sum_width)
            print('Else loop ', name)
            break

        break
    print(sum_width)
```

This is the actual output that I am getting -

```
If loop total width -  7.0
If loop  [7.0]
7.0
If loop total width -  12.0
If loop  [7.0, 5.0]
12.0
If loop total width -  16.0
If loop  [7.0, 5.0, 4.0]
16.0
If loop total width -  23.0
If loop  [7.0, 5.0, 4.0, 7.0]
23.0
```

I expect to get two clusters like -
`[7.0, 5.0, 4.0] [7.0, 2.88888889]`

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code will append the width to the `name` list regardless whether the condition (`end_x[i]>=start_x[j+1]`) is true or false. It then directly breaks out of the second loop, making it redundant.

Some changes need to be made:

1. You only need to do one-pass through the `end_x` and `start_x` lists. So only one for-loop is needed.
2. You'll need to keep track of a separate list for each cluster.

```
start_x = [ 8., 15., 20., 36., 40.]
end_x = [15., 20., 24., 43., 42.88888889]
width = [7., 5., 4., 7., 2.88888889]

sum_width = 0
clusters = [[width[0]]]     # initialise with first width

for i in range(1, len(end_x)):
    print(f'iter {i}: (start={start_x[i]}, end={end_x[i]}); width {width[i]}')

    if end_x[i-1] < start_x[i]:
        print(f'  doing a reset ({end_x[i-1]} < {start_x[i]})')
        sum_width = 0
        clusters.append([])

    sum_width += width[i]
    print('  total width:', sum_width)
    clusters[-1].append(width[i])  # append width into last cluster

print(clusters)
# [[7.0, 5.0, 4.0], [7.0, 2.88888889]]
```

Here, we iterate from second element to the end of the list, comparing the previous `end_x` element with the current `start_x` element and make a new cluster if values don't overlap.